# Output all combinations of available words in this order and with those first letters

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have entries like this

```
apple 
bee 
fork
meal
meaning
others
lawyer
```

in a table called `woerter`, the column is called `wort`.

I want to get a result that looks like this

```
column1 - column2 - column3
apple - meal - others
```

based on a `SELECT` in sqlite that you give the first letter of each columns word(in this case a-m-o) for it to output all combinations of available words in this order and with those first letters. Ie, NOT moa, NOT oma. Contents of `column1` - `column2` - `column3` all stem from `wort`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use a three-way self-join:

```
SELECT w1.wort AS column1,
       w2.wort AS column2,
       w3.wort AS column3
FROM woerter AS w1,
     woerter AS w2,
     woerter AS w3
WHERE w1.wort LIKE 'a%'
  AND w2.wort LIKE 'm%'
  AND w3.wort LIKE 'o%'
```

For this to be efficient, the `wort` column needs to have TEXT [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) and a COLLATE NOCASE index.

Comment: ambiguous column name: w2.wort